# Gradle Project Sync failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I open my project in android studio by importing the build.gradle, the project used to work fine before but now I get an error that says that the gradle project sync failed. I tried a build and it says Task '' not found in the root project 'projectname'.

This what shows up in log files.

2015-01-20 11:50:03,315 [  58495]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -
2015-01-20 11:50:03,316 [  58496]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Cause: unexpected end of block data

org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation '/home/avidbot/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.2.1'.

Comment: Help -> Show log -> paste relevant error to the question. "gradle project sync failed" is in no way enough info to give you any answer.

Comment: Have you got this fixed??

Answer (score 2):

Running: Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files, fixes it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try File > Invalidate Caches/Restarts...
This could fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

1. check this link https://gradle.org/releases/ 
   then download complete latest gradle zip file....
2. Go to C:\Users\username.gradle\dists\wrapper\
3. Extract Here .....

   Your folder name is 4.2.1-all

Then try.....